# python-behave:feature file : xpath issue

Tags: java, python, selenium-webdriver

in feature file when I want to pass multiple condition in xpath then I am getting selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException

```
Feature: showing off behave

Scenario Outline: run a simple test
    Given we have behave installed <thing> and <good>
    And Enter value in google <x_path> and <g_val>

Examples:
| thing         | good             | x_path                                     | g_val         |
| Red Tree Frog | Hello Automation |  //input[@name='q' and @class='gsfi']    | hello world   |
```

The StepDefination code is as below -

```
from behave import given
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Ie("C:\\Users\\ksahu\\Downloads\\IEDriverServer_x64_3.3.0\\IEDriverServer.exe")
driver.implicitly_wait(15)

@given(u'we have behave installed {thing} and {good}')
def step_impl(context,thing,good):
    print('============> '+thing+'===========> '+good)

@given(u'Enter value in google {x_pth} and {g_val}')
def step_impl(context,x_pth,g_val):
    driver.get("http://www.google.com")
    driver.maximize_window()
    print(x_pth)
    #driver.find_element_by_name(x_pth).send_keys(g_val)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(x_pth).send_keys(g_val)
```

The Exception is as below -

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //input[@name='q'\ and\ @class='gsfi'] because of the following error:
  Error: Bad token, expected: ] got: \


Captured stdout:
=============> Red Tree Frog==========> Hello Automation
//input[@name='q'
```

The SPACE is not allowing in xpath.

Please let me know how to pass multiple condition in xpath in feature file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick workaround would be to specify multiple conditions this way:

```
//input[@name='q'][@class='gsfi']
```

Or, I think, putting the placeholder into *backticks* should solve the space escaping issue:

```
@given(u'Enter value in google `{x_pth}` and {g_val}')
```

Comment: If you found this (or any) answer helpful, please upvote it. If this answered your question, please mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks!